# SwaggerRequestExample throws error when using a list

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger, swashbuckle

I have followed [this](https://mattfrear.com/2016/01/25/generating-swagger-example-requests-with-swashbuckle/) tutorial for setting up a custom swagger request example with Swashbuckle, for the Swagger help page.

It works fine when the API takes a single object as body argument, but when using a list I get an "Object not set to an instance of an object" exception

Here is a code example

```
using Swashbuckle.Examples;

[HttpPost]
[SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(List<TestModel>), typeof(TestExample))]     
public IHttpActionResult ListTest([FromBody] List<TestModel> tests)
{
    return Ok(tests);
}

public class TestExample : IExamplesProvider
{
    public object GetExamples()
    {
        return new List<TestModel>() {
            new TestModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Text = "First object"
            },
            new TestModel()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Text = "Second object"
            },
        };
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @HelderSepu TestModel is just an example model that has two properties int Id and string Text. The model I use is far more complex but the error is the same, so I don't think the model is the issue.
- 
If I remove SwaggerRequestExample? Yes, then it will not throw an error. But then I just get the auto generated example request, which is what I don't want and is the reason why I use SwaggerRequestExample.

Comment: @HelderSepu Correct, the difference is that this is the requestexample, not responseexample and that the request is a list

Comment: @HelderSepu Yes correct, only difference is that you're request is a single object

Comment: @HelderSepu That looks correct, what did you do different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @HelderSepu suggestion to use ApplySchemaVendorExtensions, this is what I did to make it work:

In my SwaggerConfig.cs

```
c.SchemaFilter<ApplySchemaVendorExtensions>();
```

ApplySchemaVendorExtensions.cs

```
using Swashbuckle.Swagger;    
public class ApplySchemaVendorExtensions : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, Type type)
    {
        if (schema.properties != null)
        {
            if (type == typeof(TestModel))
            {
                schema.example = new TestModel()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Text = "Custom text value"
                };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I will not mark as answer yet in case someone have a better solution.